# Google sign-in for android app

Tags: android, google-signin

I am developing an app which uses a google login and then uses the information from the account to perform an activity. The login and the activity works fine. But I am having to login every time the app is restarted. What changes do I have to make so as to make the google login only once and also be able use the first logged in account for the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I used google signIn many times, you need to call web service after after first success login with the ID provide in success response of google.

and then you can check by shared preference that user is already login or not.

If user clear the data or uninstall the app then after google service make our web service call to check ID is already register or not, and if already register you can get all stored data from your server.

Cheers :)